# how to display additional rows on click of a icon in a table in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

on click of a (+) button in the first column of each row, other rows should be expanded. but, on click of (+) button am only able to expand upto one row. how can i expand multiple rows in a table on click of (+) button. thanks in advance.

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">Vehicle Type</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr (click) = "check('car')">
      <td scope="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExamplecar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    (+)
    </button>
      </td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <td>Car</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExamplecar">
      <td></td>
      <td scope="row" >Germany</td>
      <td>Check car</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExamplecar">
      <td></td>
      <td scope="row" >Germany</td>
      <td>Check car2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
       <td scope="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExamplevan" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    (+)
    </button>
      </td>
      <td scope="row" >Germany</td>
      <td>Van</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExamplevan">
       <td></td>
      <td scope="row" >Germany</td>
      <td>Check Van</td>
    </tr>
    <tr (click) = "check('truck')">
      <td scope="row">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExampletruck" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    (+)
  </button>
      </td>
      <td scope="row">Germany</td>
      <td>Truck</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="collapse" id="collapseExampletruck">
       <td></td>
      <td scope="row" >Germany</td>
      <td>Check truck</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

how can i expand multiple rows in a table on click of (+) button. thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your js code?

Comment: Actually your question is related to Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class` instead of `id` for `data-target` attribute value. For example change

```
<button ... data-target="#collapseExamplecar" >
...
<tr class="collapse" id="collapseExamplecar">
...
<tr class="collapse" id="collapseExamplecar">
```

to

```
<button ... data-target=".collapseExamplecar">
...
<tr class="collapse collapseExamplecar">
...
<tr class="collapse collapseExamplecar">
```

Comment: kindly up vote the question if it has useful content on it @albert.